# Faster way to find out duplication of records in the table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I have to find out all the duplicate records in an table. i could get it done by using the following query

```
SELECT column4
FROM Table1
GROUP BY column1,column2,column3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but while the table contain huge records the group by is becoming very slow. is there any faster way to do it...?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: This query does not compile. What are you grouping by and what do you need to get back? Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I ran this in mysql and its working. i was looking for a query which is compactible in all databases.

Comment: How grotesque: the duplicate for this question was found rather quickly...

Comment: thank you..will look into the duplicates